# Website preloader jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, preloader

I'm making a website, and I have a problem. Or more exactly, I don't know how to solve the blank page problem.

I'm making a website, where if you swipe right, some data will be inseret in the database, and then the webpage will refresh. After refresh, a blank page is shown, and then the normal webpage with all it's html.

How can I put a loader image on the blank page before the DOM is ready? I'm using jquery and jquery mobile.

The webpage is this: http://meetmean.comxa.com/KlausApp/home.php . If you swipe to right, or left, it will show you an alert box, and then the page will refresh. I want the blank page that is shown after to be a loading image.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45599617/using-jquery-to-insert-values-into-mysql

Answer (score 1):

I had kind of the same problem and my solution is:
I covered the (blank one you were talking about) HTML page with a full screen black background and a css animation in the div , and I hide that div when the page is fully loaded using JavaScript

```
window.onload = function () { $('body').toggleClass('loaded'); };
```

This function will run when the all the content in your html body is fully loaded.
This code will add a class named loaded to your html body,
in my style.css file the loaded class will hide the full screen div. it was one of the ways to have a loader in your page and it's up to you , there are many ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Take an SVG animation file and keep it wherever you want to show it in the page.. Previously keep its display property none ..if you are using (jQuery) AJAX (i.e. `$.ajax()`) to fetch the data you can use the *on complete* callback function in the AJAX options to fadeout the SVG when the animation comes.

```
function ajaxCall(){
    $("#svg").fadeIn("slow");  
    $.ajax({url: "demo_test.txt", complete: function(result){
        $("#svg").fadeOut("slow");
    }});
}
```

Here as soon as the function is called the SVG animation appears.. and soon as AJAX gets response the SVG is faded out.
You can get loading animations from http://loading.io

Answer (score -1):

You could use some of loaders from this page: https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/pages/loader.html