# Using JQuery To Insert Values Into mySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am new to JQuery and am working on a project. This project isn't supposed to do anything, it's more of a proof of concept so I can learn. SO far I have 3 PHP files, one called 'connection.php' which connects to my local mySQL DB. Another, called 'save_score.php' which would save values to my DB. Last, I have my 'test.php' file which creates a few values and using JQuery sends them to 'save_score.php' to insert them into my DB.

The problem I have is that 'connection.php' works fine. I can hard code an INSERT INTO statement in PHP and send that query to my DB to insert it. So there is nothing wrong with the connection. I also tested, via two echo statements, whether the JQuery was actually sending the values to 'save_score.php', and the echo statements sent back my test values: 'Jeff' and "10'. However, the mySQL INSERT statement does not work to send the values and query to my DB.

So in essence, the statement I have put into '$store' should do the trick, but it's not and I do not know why.

'save_score.php':

```
<?php
  include 'connection.php';

  $name      = $_POST['name'];
  $score = $_POST['score'];

  echo $name;
  echo $score;

  $store = "INSERT INTO `galleryscores` (`player_name`, `player_score`) VALUES ($name, $score)";

  $mysqli->query($store);

  echo "done";
?>
```

'connection.php':

```
<?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $dbname = "cs301";

  // Create connection
  $mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
  // Check connection
  if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
```

'test.php':

```
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var you = 's';
    var you_score = 10;

    $.post("save_score.php", {
        name: you,
        score: you_score
      })
      .done(function(data) {
        alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
      });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you echo'd `$store` after using the variables to conclude that the SQL is still working?

Comment: I just did, and it gives me back the correct query: https://gyazo.com/a22aeb1dbe5e9cdfa5b16a88ecc9a6c2

Comment: The SQL is erroring that is why it's not updated and you've got no error handling to see it. You need to quote your string values (the S) with single quotes. Once you've got that fixed start researching mysqli or PDO and prepared statements as you are open to attack.

Comment: Your professors should be teaching you `Prepared Statements` with `mysqli` or `PDO` as @Matt stated you are open to SQL injections!!!

Comment: @cmorrissey I'm taking this course on my own, without a professor! So you guys are the next best thing! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how this should be done with `PDO`

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=cs301;host=localhost', $username, $password);

$stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO `galleryscores` (`player_name`, `player_score`) VALUES (:player_name, :player_score)');

$stmt->execute( array('player_name' => $_POST['name'], 'player_score' => $_POST['score']) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your insertion query to this

```
$store = "INSERT INTO `galleryscores` (`player_name`, `player_score`) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$score."')";
```

In order for the values to be inserted, they should be passed as string to the query. Ultimately, you are passing a String for execution.

> EDITED
>   As told by Matt you should always try and prevent SQL injection. Following shows how to do it :

```
$query = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `galleryscores` (`player_name`, `player_score`) VALUES (?, ?)");
$query->bind_param("si", $name, $score);// 's' represents the corresponding variable type is String
$query->excecute();
```

[bind_param documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: Enough to fix the issue but always try and point users to use Mysqli/PDO for prepared statements. Open to SQL Injection!

Comment: @Matt what do you mean?

Comment: @Matt Sure thing.

Comment: @Casey.PhillipsTMC If those values came from user input, say a contact us form, they could write something that can cause harm to your database -
 in terms of either dropping tables, giving themselves passwords/access to the database etc etc..Give SQL Injection a google and then give MySQLi or PDO a google (especially prepared statements). Always best, no matter where the variables come from, to use prepared statements. Safer and better practice ;)

Comment: @Matt sure thing! Thank you! My problem is that I am actually teaching myself through my Application Development class instead of actually taking the class. Being a student athlete sucks sometimes haha. Appreciate the advice!

Comment: @Casey.PhillipsTMC No worries. It was a good question and well written. Keep up the good work and hard work will prevail :D

Comment: @Casey.PhillipsTMC Not a problem Casey. You should also look at the perks of using both MySQLi and PDO implementation. They both have their own advantages.

Answer (score 0):

While we are at it. How it should be done with MySQLi :D - with error handling

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);

if($mysqli->connect_error) 
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '. $mysqli->connect_error);

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `galleryscores` (`player_name`, `player_score`) VALUES (?, ?)")) 
{
    // Bind the values in order to the ?'s or log error
    // Assuming Name is a string and score is always an int
    if(!$stmt->bind_param("si", $name, $score))
    {
        die('bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }

    // Execute the completed sql command or log error
    if (!$stmt->execute()) 
    {
        die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }

    $stmt->close(); // Close the database connection
}
else 
{
    die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
}
```

Comment: You're the best! I will come back and take a look at this to improve my code!